# Get 16 digit card number from stripe object using php api?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to store 16 digit card number from stripe object after payment succeed and use it after next payment of user . user can easily select card number and ask for cvc and so on... e.g facebook payment system . just i want to store 16 digit code instead of last 4 from  `$card` object. here is object to get last 4 digit . when i `print_r($customer);` it dose not show 16 number .it show only last 4 number array.

```
$card = $customer->sources->data[0];
$Stripe_card=$card->last4;
```

Comment: Here is a nice article about card numbers and why is it bad to share al 16 digits: http://blog.imaginecurve.com/decoding-your-credit-card/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The website does not provide all information about the card, because it is unnecessary and poses a threat of scams. In API Documentation we will find an example of what information is shared.

```
"source": {
"id": "card_1BLoXK2eZvKYlo2CUZoDPXh1",
"object": "card",
"address_city": null,
"address_country": null,
"address_line1": null,
"address_line1_check": null,
"address_line2": null,
"address_state": null,
"address_zip": null,
"address_zip_check": null,
"brand": "Visa",
"country": "US",
"customer": "cus_BjH5X2utr6sBXS",
"cvc_check": null,
"dynamic_last4": null,
"exp_month": 8,
"exp_year": 2019,
"fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
"funding": "credit",
"last4": "4242",
"metadata": {
},
"name": null,
"tokenization_method": null
},
```

Comment: Great, i already think about this answer .let me thumbs up your answer.